# Access jquery object from GWT

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, jsni, flexpaper

I am trying to access Flexpaper from GWT but the following code is not getting recognized.

```
$Flexpaper("documentViewer").getMarkList();
```

Its throwing an error such as $Flexpaper not defined. I have added js, jquery imports also to the index.html.

Can somebody help me? I just want to know how to make GWT recognize "$Flexpaper" . If not for this, can somebody tel me how to access any "$" element.

Comment: Did you add gwt-jquery or gwtquery to your dependencies and are you trying to do this in java code? Or are you adding that line to your index.html file? If it is the latter, did you add the flexpaper.js file?

Comment: I have tried by adding gwt-jquery but no luck ...I didnt add it in index.html ...shoudl I add it there? I have added the flexpaper.js file..                                                                 How would you do in this case? Can you explain me briefly?

Answer (score 0):

GWT JSNI code runs in a nested frame. For example to access browser's window object from JSNI you must use special `$wnd` reference. Try to replace all `$` in your script by `$wnd.$`:

```
$wnd.$Flexpaper("documentViewer").getMarkList();
```

Comment: Hey I ll try this and post reply but I want to know whether should I include js files in the index.html and create a div with that I'd??

Comment: Yes, you need to include corresponding JavaScript library and prepare a div with "documentViewer" id.

Comment: The thing is I have included the js library and now the error is shifted from "Flexpaper not found" to "$wnd.$Flexpaper(..) is undefined,  so the main problem is preparing the div with "documentviewer" id.  Can u explain how it can be done? I tried with various ways but still no luck and I am calling swf through gwt2swf and in a popuppanel

Comment: How you declare your GWT widgets? Do you use UiBinder?

Comment: No, just normal methods!!private SWFWidget flexPaper;      .flexPaper = new SWFWidget("../FlexPaperViewer.swf", (Window.getClientWidth() - 210), (Window.getClientHeight()) - 65); and I have added flashvars

Comment: Try something like this: `flexPaper.addStyleName("documentViewer");`

Comment: Still no luck, I am not sure where I am making a mistake. If I add the flexpaper to the root by creating a div id = "documentviewer" and adding $("#documentViewer").Flexpaper(parameters), its working but if I add it to the popup panel, its not able to find flexpaper as I tried calling through JSNI in gwt..

Comment: May be it is duplicated? If you have two divs with the same id on the page (first on the page and second in the popup) than it may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I am trying a lot from 4 days but still no luck but one thing now I am 100% sure is that its because of the id. If I place it on the rootpanel , its working fine but when I am adding it to the popuppanel, the id is not getting recognized. I used document.getElementById to verify it. Finally, I have decided to quit and before I want to try for one last time. Can you tell me the simplest way to add an id to popuppanel widget and make gwt know?

Comment: You can try something like this: `popup.getElement().setId("id");`